# Show/hide on checkbox click does not work consistently

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an inspection app to walk an inspector through a house with context-relevant questions based on answers. I am having inconsistent success with using checkboxes to show/hide div content.

I have simplified my problem down to a few very basic lines of code that I can't seem to troubleshoot.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbReplaceOrRepair_0" value="Replace" id="cbReplaceOrRepair_0" onclick="showReplaceRoof()">Replace
<div class="dvRoofReplace" id="dvReplaceRoof" style="display:none">"Replace" option is checked</div><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbReplaceOrRepair_1" value="Repair" id="cbReplaceOrRepair_1" onclick="showDvConfirmRepairability()">Repair
<div class="dvRoofRepair" id="dvConfirmRepairability" style="display:none">"Repair" option is checked</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function showReplaceRoof() {
var dvReplaceRoof = document.getElementById("dvReplaceRoof");
dvReplaceRoof.style.display = cbReplaceOrRepair_0.checked ? "block" : "none";
}
function showDvConfirmRepairability() {
var dvRoofRepair = document.getElementById("dvRoofRepair");
dvRoofRepair.style.display = cbReplaceOrRepair_1.checked ? "block" : "none";
}  
</script>
```

My example shows one checkbox that works to show/hide a div and another on that does not work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, this is my first question on here after literally years of looking up questions so I'll apologize in advance in case I messed up any of the posting protocols.

https://codepen.io/stephenskrocki/pen/EGoYaB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the element incorrectly.

The id of the second hidden element is `id="dvConfirmRepairability`.

Use `var dvRoofRepair = document.getElementById("dvConfirmRepairability");`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @FunctionalHippie No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one wanted option, instead of checkbox I would use radio buttons:

HTML Markup:

```
<style>label > span {display: none;} /* hide notes by default */</style>
<label for="replace">Replace
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="replace" onchange="radio()" />
  <span class="note">"Replace" option is checked</span>
</label>
<label for="repair">Repair
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="repair" onchange="radio()" />
  <span class="note">"Repair" option is checked</span>
</label>
```

javaScript:

```
<script>
function radio() {
  var myRadio = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio"]'); // get radio
  var myNotes = document.querySelectorAll('.note'); // get notes
  if (myRadio[0].checked === true) { // if the first radio checked
    myNotes[0].style.display = 'inline-block'; // show first note
    myNotes[1].style.display = 'none'; // hide the second
  }
  else { // if not do the apposite
    myNotes[0].style.display = 'none';
    myNotes[1].style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope it help you!

Comment: I completely agree about the radio buttons!  I had wanted to use radio buttons but had even more trouble making those work so I switched to checkboxes.  But I have not been able to make your code work?  When I copy it into code pen it doesn't work?  https://codepen.io/stephenskrocki/pen/EGoYaB

Comment: Actually i just doublecheck it and it works perfect.. look: https://codepen.io/AMeshu/pen/NeXEEW.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the code today after your edit and it works perfect!  I'm going to work that into a few places in my page!